# SSRS Report Server Configuration

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi please help I get this error when trying to create a report server

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE FILE
>   encountered operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified.) while attempting to open or create the physical file
>   'I:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MIS\MSSQL\Data\AcuideasReports_log.ldf'. CREATE
>   DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
>   related errors.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(SqlConnection
>   conn, String script, ICommandWrapperFactory commandWrapper)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(String
>   connectionString, String script)    at
>   ReportServicesConfigUI.SqlClientTools.SqlTools.ApplyScript(String
>   connectionString, String script)
>   ClientConnectionId:5e857bf6-b7aa-4427-bfe2-5d978ecced34 Error
>   Number:5123,State:10,Class:16

Comment: It looks like the path I:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MIS\MSSQL\Data\ does not exists.

Comment: thank you, found the problem it log path on the Database default Locations.